# How to fake an external server for a client device?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, proxy, http, wireless-access-point

**TL;DR**: How do I redirect all HTTP traffic of connected devices on a self-controlled Linux WiFi Access Point to Apache/nginx on the same machine and let Apache/nginx respond back?

**Scenario**: I have a hardware device ("D") which has WiFi. And I have a Linux device ("L", Ubuntu-based) that spans a Wifi network and D is connected to L. So far so good.
D has the built-in feature to do HTTP requests to some external server owned by the manufacturer (for example to check for firmware updates).

I now want L to act as this external server and fake the response to make D force into thinking there is (for example) a new firmware update.

I do not want a proxy (like `mitmproxy`) that forwards the requests to the real server or needs heavy manual user-interactions! I know the HTTP headers and body that are needed by D. I just want to directly answer with a forged response to D.

Simplified: D does a `GET http://manufacturer-server.com/firmware-version-check` and L should answer with a HTTP document forged by me. Then D will do a `GET http://manufacturer-server.com/firmware-file-download` and L should answer again like I forged it for this new URL.

What tools do I need? Since D is doing only HTTP requests and I can connect it to L, an Apache or nginx would be enough (I don't want over-complicated setups) to serve a static file for all the external endpoints I need - but how do I get the HTTP server to listen and responds to requests of the connected D? Do I need to fiddle with the DNS?

Comment: Redirecting HTTPS traffic is impossible without complete control over the client machine and the ability to replace the TLS certificate with your own.

Comment: @Ramhound you are right, of course. i changed the question. D is actually doing plain HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to start with:

- You can fiddle with DNS to override responses for the domain name, directly pointing it to your own computer.
- If the domain name currently exists and points to some specific IP address, you can DNAT that address to your own computer. (DNAT is the "port forwarding" type of NAT.)

In both cases you need *some* configuration, but probably less than setting up a proxy. For example, if you can statically configure the device's IP address (and of course the 'default gateway' it uses), then you can tell it to use your Linux server or your OpenWRT box as a gateway, which will then do DNAT even if your main router can't do that. (Linux even has a special case for "DNAT to self", the 'REDIRECT' iptables rule.)